# Data Environment

Tags: database, vb6

Any guidelines on how to pass a date parameter to a command1 object of Data Environment in VB6?? and yes I did search but didn't come across any :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to the designer view of you command. Right click the command and select *properties*, and there the tab *parameters*. Now there you can define all types of all your parameters. Select the parameter you wish to change and select *datatype* as "adDate" and host datatype as "Date (VT_DATE)". For this to work, you should have written the query into the CommandText property of the command.

I tested this with the ADO OLE provider. If you are using another provider then maybe the datatype combobox will contain different values.